# How Can I display Tabs on A Fragment?

Tags: android

My navigation drawer is built using fragments. I want to display tabs on one of the fragments. So far, nothing is showing up.  Home fragment is a fragment that is accessed upon clicking home icon on the navigation drawer. I am trying to create two tabs under home fragment without any success. I have already created a class for each tab. The classes inflate their respective layouts.

Home Fragment:

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_data_fragment, null);
    //Adding toolbar to the activity
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("ADD DATA"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("VIEW ARCHIVE"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    DailyDataPageAdapter adapter = new DailyDataPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class DailyDataPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int tabCount;

public DailyDataPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount){
    super(fm);
    this.tabCount = tabCount;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            AddData addData = new AddData();
            return addData;
        case 1:
            ViewArchive viewArchive = new ViewArchive();
            return viewArchive;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".home_activity">

<!-- our toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorgray"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<!-- View pager to swipe views -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can create a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` inside your `HomeFragment`. By the way, why do you deal with toolbar in your fragments' `onCreateView()`? Don't you have a container activity for all your fragments and toolbar is defined in this activity's layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
// Fragment List
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
// Title List
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_data_fragment,container,false);

    // init view
    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // add title to the list
    mFragmentTitleList.add("one");
    mFragmentTitleList.add("two");
    mFragmentTitleList.add("three");

    // add fragment to the list
    mFragmentList.add(new OneFragment());
    mFragmentList.add(new TwoFragment());
    mFragmentList.add(new ThreeFragment());

    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    // Tab ViewPager setting
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mFragmentList.size());
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mFragmentList, mFragmentTitleList);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * ViewPagerAdapter setting
 */
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments, List<String> titleLists) {
        super(fm);
        this.mFragmentList = fragments;
        this.mFragmentTitleList = titleLists;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList == null ? 0 : mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Still not showing the tabs after adding your suggestions.

Comment: remove  `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` of  `TabLayout`  and try it in your code .

Comment: And make sure that your `HomeFragment` display normally in your `Activity` . Is `HomeFragment` created ?

Comment: Fixed after removing android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" Thanks.

Comment: Good luck to you.@ZNZMW